# Pywikibot Installation

Tags: python, git, pywikibot

I was wondering if I could get some help setting up Pywikibot.

I was able to download it using

git clone --recursive https://gerrit.wikimedia.org/r/pywikibot/core.git

following wikipedia page instructions.

Where I get lost is when trying to create the user-config.py file using the generate_user_files.py. I get an error message saying: "No module named requests"

Thanks in advance

Comment: Now i get this when i try to run pip install requests:

Answer (score 3):

did you try install it via pip?

```
pip install requests
```

Comment: When I try I get this erro: 
DEPRECATION: Python 2.6 is no longer supported by the Python core team, please upgrade your Python. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.6

Comment: It seems that you are new to python. install python 2.7 instead.

Comment: Yea I am a beginner, but I have python 2.7.10 installed. When I check using terminal command pyhton -v in terminalit says 2.7.10

Answer (score 1):

try with the following command `sudo pip install pywikibot`
[my terminal image of the instalation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jrDEO.png)